# Winforms method/event filter attribute

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, attributes

I have been working with ASP.NET MVC for over a year now. I love ASP.NET MVC. In the meantime, every now and then I develop a Windows Forms Application. This application allows our customers to create a group structure for their webshop.

For that purpose I use a `TreeView`. How does this relate to ASP.NET MVC? Well, MVC has these action filter attributes that come in quite handy and makes the code better readable (in my opinion). I mean filters like for example the `[Authorize]` attribute, which stops the action from executing if the user is not authorized.

So the actual question is, can a simular filter be created for the methods and events in a Windows Forms Application? I need to check (in a lot of methods and events) if the `SelectedNode` property of the `TreeView` has a value. Now I do that this way:

```
private void setSelectedGroupInformation(bool refreshProductCount)
{
    GroupNode selectedNode = trvGroupTree.SelectedNode;
    if (selectedNode == null || !selectedNode.HasGroup)
        return;

    // Code that actually DOES something
}
```

But it would be nice if this would be possible:

```
[SelectedNodeRequired]
[GroupRequired]
private void setSelectedGroupInformation(bool refreshProductCount)
{
    // Code that actually DOES something
}
```

That is much better readable. I checked out the internet for this but I can't find a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be nice, but you need to do some work for it (one example, is constructing a type at runtime). What is relatively easy to do is to call some common method at first

```
[SelectedNodeRequired]
[GroupRequired]
private void setSelectedGroupInformation(bool refreshProductCount)
{
    if(MethodTester())
        return;
    // Code that actually DOES something
}

bool MethodTester()
{
    // use call stack to get caller method name
    // use reflection to get attributes of method
    // check attributes and conditions
    ...
    return true; // if has to be filtered
    ...
    return false;
}
```

But, why not making methods what actually does all logic you need to check? Like this

```
private void setSelectedGroupInformation(bool refreshProductCount)
{
    if(Global.IsGroupRequired && Global.IsSelectedNodeRequired)
    {
        // Code that actually DOES something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So there is no built-in way to do this? I like your first method thou! No way to do that without the if statement in the method?